# Incorrect Id by seed method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am observing odd behavior when i seed my database. I have three classes:
`User`, `Skill` and `SkillSet`, which i use as models to create a relation that states:

1 `User` has 1 `SkillSet`

1 `SkillSet` can contain many `Skills`.

In my seed method, when i need to fill the table for relation of Skillsets to user Id, i call these:

```
        Skill Skill1 = new Skill  { Name = "Programming", "C++" };
        Skill Skill2 = new Skill  { Name = "Programming", "Java"};
        Skill Skill3 = new Skill  { Name = "Programming", "PHP"};
        Skill Skill4 = new Skill  { Name = "Programming", "Javascript" };

        context.Skills.AddOrUpdate(Skill1,Skill2,Skill3,Skill4);

        SkillSet SkillSet1 = new SkillSet();
        SkillSet1.UserId = 1;
        SkillSet1.Skills.Add(Skill1);
        SkillSet1.Skills.Add(Skill2);

        SkillSet SkillSet2 = new SkillSet();
        SkillSet2.UserId = 2;
        SkillSet2.Skills.Add(Skill2);
        SkillSet2.Skills.Add(Skill3);

        SkillSet SkillSet3 = new SkillSet();
        SkillSet3.UserId = 3;
        SkillSet3.Skills.Add(Skill1);
        SkillSet3.Skills.Add(Skill4);

        context.SkillSets.AddOrUpdate(SkillSet1, SkillSet2,SkillSet3);
```

Here is the code of `Skill` and `SkillSet` classes

```
public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Platform
    public string TechnologyName { get; set; }
}

public class SkillSet
{
    public SkillSet()
    {
        Skills = new List<Skill>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that after I update the database and seed method is called, 
the table for relations between `SkillSet` and `User` looks very odd and with inverted Id's.
Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Can someone explain why the Id's are inverted?

Comment: If content is right then EF is free to insert objects in the order it prefers...

Comment: But in this case if in table `Users`, a `user` has id of 1 and SkillsetID of 1, and in the `SkillSet` a skillset with id 1 does not reffer to a user with id 1, doesn't that mean that the data in the tables is incorrect?

Comment: Why have both Id and UserId columns? You shouldn't need two ID's.

Comment: &Alexander check IDs on code side but I'd bet they are right. Relative insertion order is up to EF